# jasper report show count on footer of a specific query

Tags: jasper-reports

am very new to jasper report
also I have tried looking at videos but can not seem to get this one concept
basically there is this main query  which i have

```
select * from table
```

which is populated in the details area
however i want a second query

```
select count(*) from table where name = "tim"
```

and put the count on the footer

can this be done using jasper
any tutorial to this concept or guidance would be helpful

- to sum up the details area should show all the data where as the footer should only show counts of a few things.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one DataSet (therefore query) for the report.  In your case this is your main report `select * from table`, which seems to be working well.

You have two options for adding the information you want:

1. (and I would say the better option) is to add a variable `$V{tim_count}` which is configured as:

- initial value 0
- expression value `"tim".equals($F{name}) ? 1 : 0"`
- calculation function `sum`

there are multiple ways to increment this variable, so I'll leave that with you.  In the footer you would then add a text field with the `$V{tim_count}` variable as it's contents.

You can read about variables here https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/variables

2. You can add an object that has it's own DataSet:

- Table
- List
- Subreport

You would then be able to add your query to that object and display it appropriately.   As you can see, displaying a COUNT is not really the most appropriate way to do this.

**Note - I don't suggest this way**